# Is it possible to get the area of a circular segment without having to use the formula derived from manipulation of the area of a circle?

Tags: geometry, circles, area

This may sound naïve but is there maybe a way in which one could use some sort of calculus or any other method of finding the area of a circular segment. Given that you have the dimensions of the "height" and the "base" of the segment. I am attempting to find this information in an effort to prove the area of a circle by inscribing a square in a circle, finding the area of that square and all that's left are the areas of the 4 equal segments formed as a result of the inscribed triangle.

See the following image for the image of a segment. The length of my red line is 2^1/2r in which r is the radius of the circle.
[image: image of a segment]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_segment

Comment: Why don't you obtain area of the circle thru integration instead?

Comment: @Vasili how exactly would one do that( as in which rule and etc)

Comment: For a circle, $A = 4\int_0^r\sqrt{r^2 - x^2}\,dx$. Make a substitution $x = r\sin\theta$, apply a couple trig formulas to change the result into something you know how to integrate (I assume you know the integrals of sine and cosine), and there it is.

Comment: see comment from @PaulSindair above, this is a standard area under the curve approach, use circle centered at the origin, break it into four quarters and find area of one quarter.

Comment: thank you for the assistance!!!